# Is there a way to determine if an order requires shipping?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, shipping

We're selling a mix of both tangible and digital products with Commerce.

If an order doesn't require shipping, I'd rather just take them to directly to the final one page checkout/payment form.

Is there a way to determine this natively or do I need to add a "RequireShipping" field and loop through the line items to see if one exists in the user's cart?

Answer (score 1):

[Commerce_OrderModel](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/order-model) has a [`getShippingMethod()`](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/order-model#getshippingmethod) that will return a `Commerce_ShippingMethodModel` class of the current shipping method, or null if nothing has been set.

If you've already got the order in the template is should be as simple as:

```
{% if order.getShippingMethod() %}
    Shipping.
{% else %}
    No shipping.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: As a follow up question, Is there a way to check for this similar thing at the cart level? For example, I have not checked out yet, but all products in my cart have `freeShipping` selected. At this point, I don't know if my whole order qualifies for free shipping so I am checking each line item. Is `cart.totalShippingCost` accurate at this point in the checkout process?

Comment: A cart is just an [OrderModel](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/order-model#overview) with its `isCompleted` property set to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think somewhere in-between Brad's answer and this is the solution...

I too have a mix of tangible and tangible products on my site. In the CP I have checked the "Free Shipping" checkbox for all non-tangible products when I create them.

Because I eventually *will* have products that require shipping, I didn't want to completely do away with the shipping screen. Here is what I came up with.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

After working through this more, I wanted to provide more insight for others who might come across this thread. As always if there is room for improvement, please let me know so it can be updated.

**/shop/checkout/addresses/**

```
{% set freeShipping  = false %}

{% for item in cart.lineItems %}
    {% set variant = item.purchasable %}
    {% set product = variant.product %}

    {% if product.freeShipping %}
        {% set freeShipping = true %}
    {% else %}
        {% set freeShipping = false %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

...

<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/updateCart">

{% if freeShipping %}
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="shop/checkout/payment"/>
{% else %}
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="shop/checkout/shipping"/>
{% endif %}


...

{% if freeShipping %}
    <input type="hidden" name="sameAddress" value="1">
{% else %}
    <input type="hidden" name="sameAddress" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sameAddress" id="sameAddress"
                                               checked="checked">Use same address for shipping
{% endif %}


...

{% if freeShipping %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continue To Payment</button>
{% else %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continue To Shipping</button>
{% endif %}

<span>or <a href="{{ url('/shop/cart') }}">Return to cart</a></span>
```

What I'm doing here is looping through my cart to see if `freeShipping` has been selected for every product (see above). Later I check the same var and handle the form redirect appropriately. If all products in my cart are set to `freeShipping` I don't really want to make the user have to enter a shipping address. So I will set the `sameAddress` for them. This way we still have a shipping address should we need it in the future. Then at the end changing the next button accordingly as well.

**/shop/checkout/payment**

```
{% set freeShipping  = false %}
{% for item in cart.lineItems %}
    {% set variant = item.purchasable %}
    {% set product = variant.product %}

    {% if product.freeShipping %}
        {% set freeShipping = true %}
    {% else %}
        {% set freeShipping = false %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


...

{% for adjustment in cart.adjustments %}
    <div class="adjustment">
        {% if adjustment.name == "Free Shipping" %}
            {% if not freeShipping %}
                <h4>{{ adjustment.name }}</h4>
                <p>{{ adjustment.amount|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}
                                    ({{ adjustment.description }})</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            <h4>{{ adjustment.name }}</h4>
            <p>{{ adjustment.amount|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}
            ({{ adjustment.description }})</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}


...


{% if not cart.shippingMethod %}
    {#
    If the order requires a shipping method be selected, you could redirect back to the shipping page until one is applied to the order.
    {% redirect "shop/checkout/shipping" %}
    You might also want to add a php plugin hook to require
    #}
    {% if freeShipping %}
        {# Shipping not applicable. #}
    {% else %}
        <p><strong>Shipping</strong> None selected. <a href="{{ url('shop/checkout/shipping') }}">
        Choose a shipping method.</a>
        </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Same thing here, checking for `freeShipping` on all items. The biggest change here is (purely cosmetic) I didn't want to show "Free Shipping" since we aren't shipping anything. The last part is just updating existing shipping logic to accommodate the free shipping.

**/shop/checkout/shipping**

```
{% set freeShipping  = false %}

{% for item in cart.lineItems %}
    {% set variant = item.purchasable %}
    {% set product = variant.product %}

    {% if product.freeShipping %}
        {% set freeShipping = true %}
    {% else %}
        {% set freeShipping = false %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

...

{% if freeShipping %}
    <p>None of the items in your cart require shipping.</p>
    <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/updateCart">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="shop/checkout/payment">
        <input type="hidden" name="shippingMethod" value="freeShipping">
        {{ getCsrfInput() }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continue to payment</button>         
    </form>
{% else %}
    <h3>Shipping Method</h3>
    <p>Select a shipping method below.</p>

    ...
{% endif %}
```

All we are doing here is checking (again) for `freeShipping`. If everything qualifies, I only show a button that tells the customer they don't have anything to ship and I send them to the `/payment` screen. I suppose you *could* just set a `{% redirect %}` as well.

Comment: Thanks. I may end up doing something like what you've suggested. I'm still getting my head around the way shipping works...Shipping Categories and Methods and Zones, Oh my...

Comment: What I struggled with was I wanted to check if the cart had anything that qualified for shipping before actually getting to the shipping screen. So I don't think checking `cart.totalShippingCost` would be accurate since I haven't even gotten to that screen yet. Hope this helps, I'd be interested to know what you come up with!